# How to get all user inputted data inside a form, considering you don't know how many input texts there are in Flask/Mysql

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, flask, backend

I am currently working on a project that involves recipes. The front end HTML looks like this
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysKiO.png)

The idea is that the user will input what ingredients they have, and when they click "submit" my program will query through a MySQL database to show what recipes they can make with the ingredients they listed. 
As you can see, the user can input as many ingredients as they want.

In the javascript, I made it so that each input box has an incrementing ID. So the first input box has an id of "input1" and the second input box has an id of "input2" and so on.

What strategy should I use to gather all the data that the user input? Should I put everything into an array using javascript, and then pass the array to the backend where the array can be read and put into a Mysql query? The thing with an array is that I don't know how big it should be because I don't know how many inputs the user will choose. 
The backend language I am using is python and Flask.

Comment: Both JS and Python use dynamic memory, so you don't need to think about how big the array will be. I think it would be enough to grab the inputs from the page using something like document.querySelectorAll, loop through the items and grab the .value property and push that into an array before sending it to your backend.

Comment: For the backend, take a look at wtforms fieldlists.